# How to correctly type a null value in typescript react app, retrieved from an JSON object (api call) when using Object.entries to retrieve the value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The object, named "questions" looks like this:

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "paths": {
        "Yes": 2,
        "No": null
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "paths": {
        "Yes": 5,
        "No": null
     }
 }
]
```

I typed the response:

```
type Paths =  {
[key: string]: number;}

type Grid = {
paths:Paths;
id:number;
questions: {};
onUpdateQuestion(selectedQuestion: number): void;
}
```

I create a functional component that looks like this:

```
function QuestionGrid ({questions, onUpdateQuestion}:Grid) {

const {paths}:Paths = questions  
const pathentries = Object.entries(paths);  // this line is listed as causing the error

    return (    
        <div>

        <div>
            {pathentries.map(([key, value]) => (

            <button className="button" key={key}

            onClick={() => onUpdateQuestion(value)}>
                {key}

            </button> 


            ))}

        </div>

        </div>
    )}
```

I have this working in a React app without typescript but with typescript I get the following error:  **TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

Comment: questions above is a list not an object. So it wont destructure.

Comment: Thank you Tobias.  I am new to both react and typescript. The api I am calling does return a JSON object with I destructure with the code above. I was not sure how to present the object here.  I have edited to show the object with out the attempt to create it...

Comment: Tobias and Andrew were correct.  The issue was the example above represented an array - starting with [ and ending with ] of objects.  My confusion was that I thought the api was returning the array but it was not it was only returning one question as an object.  So my non-typescript app worked because I called Object.entries on an object my typescript did not.   Thank you both again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to de-structure `paths` out of `questions`.
`questions` does not have a `paths` property, since it is a list. Your questions list has multiple objects and these objects indeed have a `paths` property.

So, could it be that you do not want to pass the whole list of questions to your `QuestionGrid`, but a single question?

This will not work, but is exactly what currently happens:

```
const {paths}:Paths = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "paths": {
      "Yes": 2,
      "No": null
    }
  }
]
```

This would work:

```
const {paths}:Paths = {
  "id": 1,
  "paths": {
    "Yes": 2,
    "No": null
  }
}
```

Maybe this little stackblitz can help you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gnhhd8

Comment: Tobias, first thank you for taking the time. Second, thank you for doing the stackblitz, I have created an account and am trying to figure this out now.   Indeed the purpose of the grid is to display one question but the "paths" will not always be yes or no.   Hopefully I can understand your comment in a few days

Answer (score 2):

`Object.entries()` on an array is not valid. You de-structured `paths` from `questions`, which is an array.

you can try:

```
const pathentries = paths.map(path => Object.entries(path)).flat();
```

which should retain the format you want for later down the script

```
[ [ 'Yes', 2 ], [ 'No', null ], [ 'Yes', 5 ], [ 'No', null ] ]
```

Comment: Andrew thank you for you suggestion.  However, my lack of knowledge on this is perhaps misdirecting the issue.  I have this working fine in a React app. Just not a typescript compiled app.  I am unsure what to call "questions" - I am unsure what to call the structure of it by my api shows it like above.  I use fetch to get the data and when I use Object.entries(path) it does give me what I need.  My issue is I do not know how to resolve the type error  of  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object  Again I could be totally wrong here but since it is working in a react only app...